# Formatting Visual Studio C# Reports at runtime

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I asked a similar question yesterday. I have a large MS Access application that I want to convert into C#. On the whole I'm doing ok, but it's become apparent to me that I've got problems when formatting reports. Yesterday I was asking about changing a report title at runtime. I came up with a workaround for that. However, MS Access allows you at runtime to create, move, hide, reveal and resize report controls. In particular, my MS Access application constructs barcodes in reports at runtime. In the report I have an array of lines that my code places and resizes in order to construct the barcode. As far as I can see, this is completely impossible in a Visual Studio report. Do I have any options here? For instance are there any competent 3rd party solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

1. You can use a 3rd party custom report item like [Aspose Barcode for Reporting Services](http://www.aspose.com/reporting-services/barcode-component.aspx).
2. You can dynamically [generate an image with embedded code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/789254/How-to-embed-Barcodes-in-your-SSRS-report).

***Note:*** I've never attempted the 2nd option, but it seems like it has potential to be an easy way to dynamically generate images for a report...

Comment: Thanks. I think I might go down the embedded image route. 25 years ago I wrote the firmware for a thermal printer in classic C. This is the first time I touched C since those days. Back then I wrote routines to construct barcodes in the printer's print buffer and i've still got the source code (I think). So it will be a useful exercise to see if I can generate my own .bmp files.